# Is it possible to get all references of a property in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, reflection

I want to write a script which shows all references on a property of a class (similar to pressing F12 in Visual Studio).

It should run in powershell or as a C# .net console application.

The main task of the script is to delete unused DataModels of a DataContext.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Not sure what you want, but try press `F12`.

Comment: I want to do exactly this in a script to get all references in my code.

Comment: I suspect you would need to use Roslyn and going through its ASTs to find references: this is information the compiler has not not the runtime.

Comment: Where should that script run? Are you developing a Visual Studio extension (vsix)? Or an external tool that should analyse your code?

Comment: It could run in PowerShell but it could also be a C# console application. I have to get all references of all DbSet<T>s in my DataContext to see which models are in use.

Comment: @Richard Thank you very munch! This was exactly I was searching for.

Comment: Hi Noah,

I've noticed that your question seems to be answered but there was a lot of confusion about your question. Can you update your question to be clearer about the type of script? Maybe with an example where you wanted to find these references?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want to use the reflection to get the references of a class.

I make a code example in the console app. You can check if it is useful for you.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Student stu = new Student();
            Type type = stu.GetType();
            var members = type.GetMembers().ToList();
            foreach (var item in members)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }

        }
    }


    public class Student
    { 
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public int Age { get; set; }

        public void SayHello(string Name)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello , I am {0}",Name);
        }

        public int ClassID { get; set; }



    }
```

Result:

[image]